# uniformly convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(z^n)$ on every compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. $f(0)=0$. Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(z^n)$ is uniformly convergent on every compact subsets of $\mathbb{D}$.

I have a hint but I can't use it.

Hint: Schwarz lemma on $|z|<r$

Comment: It is  $f:\mathbb{D}→\mathbb{C}  $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0<r<1$. As $f$ is continuous on $\{|z|\leq r\}$, then we denote $M=\max_{|z|\leq r}|f(z)|$ and $g(z)=M^{-1}f(rz)$ for $|z|<1$, then $|g(z)|\leq 1$ and hence $|g(z)|\leq|z|$, so $|f(w)|\leq Mr^{-1}|w|$ for $|w|<r$, and hence $|f(z^{n})|\leq Mr^{n-1}$ for $|z|<r$.

Answer (score 1):

So, we can’t apply the Schwartz lemma directly. It turns out it’s not important, as the constant $1$ in the bound $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ isn’t really important. Let $0 < R <1$, and let $K$ be the maximum of $|f’(z)|$ on $R \overline{D} \subset \subset D$.

Then, for all $z$ with $|z| \leq R$, $|f(z)| \leq K|z|$.

So, if $n \geq 1$ and $|z| \leq R$, $|f(z^n)| \leq K|z|^n \leq KR^n$, as $R < 1$.

So the series of functions converges normally on $RD$, which yields the desired proof.

Comment: How do you get $|f(z)| \leq K|z|$?

Comment: $f(z)=z\int_0^1{f’(tz)\,dt}$...